# No error or exception, but code does not play audio file in WPF application

Tags: c#, wpf, audio

I use this code to play an audio (`.wav`) file in a WPF application written in C#. This is my code to play the audio file:

```
Uri uri = new Uri(@"C:\Users\naseem\source\repos\ChatBotAssistant\ChatBotAssistant\bin\Debug\Speech.wav");
MediaPlayer player = new MediaPlayer();
player.Open(uri);
player.Play();
```

There is no error and no exception but it does not play the audio file.

Comment: works perfectly fine for me in .net 4.7.2. Which version of .net are you using? Also are you able to play the file with Windows media player app.

Answer (score 0):

The `MediaPlayer` will not throw an exception when the media file cannot be opened. In general, you should use the following events to circumvent playback and loading issues for `MediaPlayer`.

- [MediaOpened](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.mediaplayer.mediaopened?view=netcore-3.1) - Occurs when the media is opened.
- [Media Failed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.mediaplayer.mediafailed?view=netcore-3.1) - Occurs when an error is encountered.

When `MediaOpened` is fired, you can safely call `Play` and when `MediaFailed` is fired, you can handle errors, as the media is not loaded then. The `ExceptionEventArgs` will contain the `Exception` that occurred.

```
private void ButtonBase_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   var uri = new Uri(@"C:\Users\naseem\source\repos\ChatBotAssistant\ChatBotAssistant\bin\Debug\Speech.wav");
   var player = new MediaPlayer();
   player.MediaOpened += OnMediaOpened;
   player.MediaFailed += OnMediaFailed;
   player.Open(uri);
}

private void OnMediaOpened(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   var player = (MediaPlayer)sender;
   player.Play();
}

private void OnMediaFailed(object sender, ExceptionEventArgs e)
{
   var exception = e.ErrorException;
   // Handle exception
}
```

Comment: when i use this code then firstly it show a warning that is [This asyn lacks "await" operator an d will synchronously.Consider using the "await" operator to await non blocking API calls,or 'await Task.Run(...)' to do CPU-bound work on a background thread.] and still not play audio.@thatguy

Comment: @AhmadKabeer Sorry, the `async` keyword should not be in there at all, my bad. I have adapted the sample code. Did you have a look  at `exception`? What does it say?